# Localization related Error on Xib in Xcode 10

Tags: localization, xib, xcode10

I am getting the following Error pointing one of my Xib. This happens after running in Xcode 10. Please help me on this.

> Companion strings files can only be specified for base-localized
>   documents.  The output path directory does not end with Base.lproj.

Answer (score 3):

The localisation workflow has changed in Xcode 10. You can find a lot of Videos about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/frameworks/internationalization-and-localization).

In your specific case the problem is that Xcode does not support localisable strings in combination with xib files without base localisation anymore. You will have to convert the strings to a "interface builder cocoa touch xib". You can change this in the interface builder and Xcode will automatically convert the file. [image: Screenshot of interface builder]

Comment: Thanks @And. I have tried as u said. ie, changing the localizable string to Interface Builder Cocoa Xib. I am having English and Arabic support. So after this I am not having Localizable string both English and Arabic as Interface Builder Cocoa Xib. Thecode is working now. But I am having doubt after watching the Apple New localization, Instead of changing to interface Builder cocoa xib, I have untic the English and tic Base. So I am having Arabic as "Localizable string" itself. Now this is also working fine. Do u have any idea, which one to follow.